# Form not submitting after email JSON validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I am validating a form on a registration page, everything works properly except the email validation is a bit hit and miss.

It works fine if I just validate it to make sure it's an actual email address, but when I try to add a check to see if its in use as well I run in to problems.

The validation itself works fine, but the form won't submit once its validated and not in use.

This works, and the form submits:

```
if(filter.test(a)){
        email.removeClass("field_error");
        emailInfo.text("");
        emailInfo.removeClass("error");
        return true;
    }
```

This works, but the form does not submit:

```
if(filter.test(a)){
        $.post('php/availability.php',{email: $('#email').val()}, function(emaildata){
            if(emaildata.exists){
                email.addClass("field_error");
                emailInfo.text("(Email address in use)");
                emailInfo.addClass("error");
            } else {
                email.removeClass("field_error");
                emailInfo.text("");
                emailInfo.removeClass("error");
                return true;
            }
        }, 'JSON');
    }
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: What's coming back in emaildata?

Comment: It returns 'exists'. {"exists":true} to be exact.

Comment: If it's returning `{"exists":true}`, then your email address is in use and the form shouldn't submit. Maybe I'm not understanding correctly.

Comment: Yes, it stops it when the email exists. But once the email is allowed it still won't submit the form.

Comment: I think your problem is due to the async nature of AJAX calls.  See my answer below.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with the asynchronous nature of an AJAX call (the first 'A').

In your first example, you fall into the `if` block and immediately return `true`, which I assumes allows your form to submit.

However, in your second example, you fall into the `if` block but then you asynchronously call a web resource (`availability.php`).  Your code makes the AJAX call (the `$.post()` call) and then immediately hits the end of your `if` block.  `True` isn't returned, so your form doesn't get submitted.

What you need to do is to:

- move your `exists===false` logic to a separate function;
- in your `if` block, if the email is valid, you call the function;
- your function finds the form (say with jQuery) and then submits it

So your revised code could look like:

```
if(filter.test(a)){
        $.post('php/availability.php',{email: $('#email').val()}, function(emaildata){
            if(emaildata.exists){
                email.addClass("field_error");
                emailInfo.text("(Email address in use)");
                emailInfo.addClass("error");
            } else {
                submitForm(email, emailInfo);
            }
        }, 'JSON');
    }
```

And then `submitForm()` does something like:

```
function submitForm(email, emailInfo){
  email.removeClass("field_error");
  emailInfo.text("");
  emailInfo.removeClass("error");
  $('#theForm').submit();
}
```

I think, then, you should see your form submit.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there are multiple validations that have to be completed in order to return true on the form submit. Would this override those and submit the form anyway? Or would this just send another submit call, triggering the remaining validations?

Comment: If your submit is dependent on the email existing, then you should encapsulate that in a function that gets called when your `$.post` returns.  Whether this is a second function that's called from the `submitForm` function I created above, or if it's all in a single function (i.e. put all your validation in `submitForm`).  The thing to remember is that your `$.post` call is asynchronous, so your validation needs to fire after `$.post` returns.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind and see what I can do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem - glad I could be of help!